# check to see if 1st option is selected

Tags: jquery

How would I check to see if the first option is selected and then execute some code.

Something like, if select box named "My_Saved_Shipping" has the 1st option selected then execute the code.

```
<select name="My_Saved_Shipping">
<option>Select/Enter Address</option>
<option value="1">text</option>
<option value="2">text2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($("select[name='My_Saved_Shipping']").selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        //This is where your code goes
        alert('First Element is selected');
    }
</script>
```

If you want to test for the text within the `option`, use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($("select[name='My_Saved_Shipping']").text == 'Select/Enter Address')
    {
        //This is where your code goes
        alert('First Element is selected');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How does this construct work? Doesn't $("select[name='My_Saved_Shipping']") return a JQuery collection? There isn't a selectedIndex property on it... I had to use the $("select[name='My_Saved_Shipping']")[0] approach to get to the DOM element which has the selectedIndex property.

Comment: add [0] to your answer, should be like this: if($("select[name='My_Saved_Shipping']")[0].selectedIndex == 0)

Answer (score 23):

```
if ( $('select[name=My_Saved_Shipping]')[0].selectedIndex === 0 ) {
    // do something
}
```

It'd be best to give the `<select>` an `id` (typically matching the `name`) - an `#id` selector is faster than a `[attr=val]` selector.

Comment: In his example, it's however the 2nd option (which has an index of 1). I think the question is best to be reinterpreted as "Execute code when first option **with a value** is selected" ;)

Comment: @BalusC, how do we know which `<option>` the OP is referring to?

Comment: For whatever reason this is not working on the page even though it should. How would we check selected text "Select/Enter Address" instead of the index = 0?

Comment: @user357034: If you want to test the current value then try: `if( $('select[name=My_Saved_Shipping]').val() === 'some string' ) ...`

Comment: To get the 'Select/Enter Address' part, use `.text == 'Select/Enter Address'`

Comment: @user How are you invoking this script, can you verify that its even being called?  Maybe you could add what you've got so far to the OP.  I'm wondering if maybe you haven't added the code to wire up your javascript to the onchange/onclick/whatever handler for the element.  (since no-one has provided that and you don't have access to the markup which would just allow you to add it there)...edited my answer to better show what I'm talking about

Answer (score 19):

This is another method:

```
$('.myselect').change(function() { 
    if ($(this).children('option:first-child').is(':selected')) {
       //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: the most strictly jQuery answer for me

Comment: Thanks best answer

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Modified selector to work off of name, also added code to wireup to the change handler for the select, and placed in the ready handler.

```
$(function(){ 
        $("select[name='My_Saved_Shipping']").change(function() {            
            if (this.selectedIndex == 0){
                 <!-- do stuff -->
                }
          });
});
```

Comment: @user357034 updated, also included the jquery to wire up to the change event for the select

Comment: Favorable solution - detect, solid, and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use somthing like:

```
<select name="My_Saved_Shipping">
  <option value="-1">Select/Enter Address</option>
  <option value="1">text</option>
  <option value="2">text2</option>
</select>
```

and test if value is negative ?